# String to Object Serialization using .NET

Tags: .net, serialization

I'm working on a project that uses .NET as main framework. I used to be in Java development. My question is, is it possible in .NET to convert a JSON formatted string into .NET object.

```
// String
"{ id: 1, firstname: "Foo", lastname: "Bar"}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe there is a `JSONDataContractSerializer` class somewhere hidden in obscure assembly. Google/MSDN will help you find it.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. all keys and string values must be quoted with double quotes (").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [.Net Json serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

Use following Code

```
using (System.IO.MemoryStream oStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(YOUR_JSON_STRING)))
                {
                    oStream.Position = 0;
                    return new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE)).ReadObject(oStream);
                }
```